# Passing Props in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I am trying to understand how props work. At the moment I have an array which I want to send to another component. But the input components shows the props value as

> "Undefined"

. Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react;
import ReceiveData from "./ReceiveData";

const Data =() = {
const sendData = ["1A", "2A", "3A", "4A", "1B", "2B", "3B", "1C", "2C", "3C", "4C", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4D", "4B"];
<ReceiveData data ={sendData} />
}
export default Data;
```

Code for ReceiveData component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react;
    function ReceiveData(props){
     console.log("Props Output: ", props.data);
    }
    export default ReceiveData;
```

Where am I going wrong? Sorry of my question is very trivial. Thanks in advance,

Comment: You missed the return statement: `return <ReceiveData data ={sendData} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few syntax issues like single quote missing on both files, and `=>` arrow was missing in `Data()` function and also `return` statment missing

I write updated code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReceiveData from "./ReceiveData";

const Data = () => {
const sendData = ["1A", "2A", "3A", "4A", "1B", "2B", "3B", "1C", "2C", "3C", "4C", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4D", "4B"];
   return <ReceiveData data ={sendData} />
}
export default Data;
```

For the second file

```
import React from 'react';
    function ReceiveData(props){
         console.log("Props Output: ", props.data);

         return <div>html code here</div>
    }
export default ReceiveData;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Data = () => {
  const sendData = ["1A", "2A", "3A", "4A", "1B", "2B", "3B", "1C", "2C", "3C", "4C", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4D", "4B"];
  return <ReceiveData data={sendData} />;
};
```

You missed a couple of things in your Data function component. A return statement and missing arrow on your fat arrow syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to below code.

```
const Data = () => {
  const sendData = ["1A", "2A", "3A", "4A", "1B", "2B", "3B", "1C", "2C", "3C", "4C", "1D", "2D", "3D", "4D", "4B"];
  return (<ReceiveData data ={sendData} />)
}
```

```
function ReceiveData(props){
  console.log("Props Output: ", props.data);

  return <div>something</div>
 }
```

First, Data component return ReceiveData component. And modify arrow function.

Second, Add something return element in ReceiveData component.